# Logging in with sha1() encryption

Tags: php, sha1

Hey guys,  I added this to my sign up code :

```
$password=mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($_POST['password']));
```

and now it inserts the password into the database while its encrypted. But signing in doesn't seem to work anymore. Here is the login code.

```
function checklogin($username, $password){
            global $mysqli;

        $password=sha1($password);
            $result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? and password=?");
            $result->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
            $result->execute();

        if($result != false){

            $dbArray=$result->fetch();


            if(!$dbArray){
                echo '<p class="statusmsg">The username or password you entered is incorrect, or you haven\'t yet activated your account. Please try again.</p><br/><input class="submitButton" type="button" value="Retry" onClick="location.href='."'login.php'\">";
                return;
            }
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;

            if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
                setcookie("jmuser",$username,time()+60*60*24*356);  
                setcookie("jmpass",$password ,time()+60*60*24*356);
            }

        redirect();
        }
```

Comment: I just accepted the previous question I asked, but it's still 0%.

Comment: you don't need to run `mysql_real_escape_string` on sha1 as it does not contain any invalid chars.

Comment: Does it fail on all logs, or just the old ones? I mean, if you've just added the sha1, the old users would still have plaintext passwords in your db

Comment: setcookie("jmpass",$password ,time()+60*60*24*356); // Please don't do things like this.. PLEASE

Comment: sha1() is NOT encryption - it's a hash. Encryption is a two way operation (you can encrypt and decrypt). Hashing is one way, you can only convert something into a hash, but in theory never go from the hash back to whatever you had originally.

Comment: @Nanne, I am testing this on a localhost and I created an account after typing the code. I checked my mysql database and the password is hashed.
@DampeS8N Why not? The password is hashed.

Comment: @samir-ghobril : did you also echo the password-hash you're comparing it against? just do some debugging, see why it isn't hitting the spot....   @marc-b (encryption it is not, but you don't want to be able to decrypt a password, so all's clear).

Comment: Ok I got the problem, in the mysql database it was configured that the password isnt larger than 30 characters. I just need to fix that, reset the password, and I'm set. Thanks for the help. How can I check an answer?

Comment: @samir, you seem to be asking questions with one line of information then posting lines of code. Please read this:  http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Answer (score 3):

Don't design an authentication system if you are new to cryptography and security. This is an actual answer.

You don't log in with sha1. You don't store passwords like that. You don't authenticate like that. You don't create session keys or cookies like that.

You need to read up on best practices.

Here's a link to the [RSA PKCS #5 v2.1 standard for password based cryptography](ftp://ftp.rsa.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-5v2/pkcs5v2_1.pdf). You need to start here for an understanding of issues related to passwords.

You should read PKCS #3 or RFC2631 to understand how to set up your cookies.

You should read OWASP's information about session IDs to prevent session hijacking.

There's a wealth of tutorials on this stuff, but I understand it's hard to tell what's good information and what's bad when everyone is making their own claims. I suggest starting with [these courses from google](http://saweis.net/crypto.html) on encryption, it may give you a background knowledge to help you reason what's good and what's bad.

You're best off using one of the other long-existing and well tested authentication schemes.

---

All that being said, you're probably running the $password variable through sha1 two times.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the mysql_real_escape_string anywhere for this.
Also, instead of storing the password in the $_COOKIE, generate a unique id/login and user agent hash, maybe by hashing

```
$key=md5(time().uniqueid().$user_id); $ua=md5($_SERVER['user_agent']);
```

and store $key & $ua in your users database along with the expiry time.
Also store the $user_id, $key and $ua in cookies (and session) with expiry set accordingly.

Then when you find a user with a cookie/session with ckey/ua set, check if their current user_agent is same as stored, if the $key corresponds to key in db with the user and if the expiration time has elapsed. (Don't trust expiry of cookies, they can be extended manually)